# Do ColdFusion Scheduled Tasks have a built-in request timeout?

Tags: coldfusion, timeout, scheduled-tasks, coldfusion-11

I have several scheduled tasks that essentially perform the same type of functionality:

1. Request JSON data from an external API
2. Parse the data
3. Save the data to a database

The "Timeout (in seconds)" field in the Scheduled Task form is empty for each task.

Each CFM template has the following line of code at the top of the page:

```
<cfscript>
    setting requesttimeout=299;
</cfscript>
```

However, I consistently see the following entries in the scheduled.log file:

> "Information","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8","04/24/19","12:23:00",,"Task
>   default - Data - Import triggered."
>
> "Error","DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-8","04/24/19","12:24:00",,"The
>   request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: cfhttp "

**Notice, there is only a 1-minute difference between the start of the task, and its timing out.**

I know that, [according to Charlie Arehart](https://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2010/10/15/lies_damned_lies_and_cf_timeouts), the timeout error messages that are logged are usually not indicative of the actual cause/point of the timeout, and, in fact, I have run tests and confirmed that the CFHTTP calls generally run in a matter of 1-10 seconds.

Lastly, when I make the same request in a browser, it runs until the `requesttimeout` set in the CFM page is reached.

This leads me to believe that there is some "forced"/"built-in"/"unalterable" request timeout for Scheduled Tasks, or, that it is using the default timeout value for the server and/or application (which is set to 60 seconds for this server/application) yet, I cannot find this documented anywhere.

**If this is the case, is it possible to scheduled a task in ColdFusion that runs longer than the forced request timeout?**

Comment: .. Oops, reading too quick I missed the part where you already said that , i.e. "[may be] using the default timeout value for the server". Though I'd still like to know whether setting a scheduled task timeout changes the behavior you've observed.

Comment: Putting the desired value in the Scheduled Tasks form when you set it up actually works.

Comment: Sorry, but, this did not work for me. In CF Admin, I set an overall default timeout of 10 seconds, set a timeout of 15 seconds for a request that runs an infinite loop, and it timed out at 10 seconds. I also added `<cfsetting requesttimeout="15" />` to the page, and it still timed out at 10 seconds. It seems that the default timeout is overriding any other timeouts attempted.

Comment: I cannot find any workaround for this. I have submitted a bug to Adobe.

Comment: @EricBelair Shot in the dark. But check your web server timeout as well. We had simillar time out issue. In the end we found out that our web server (tomcat) was timing out.